EsLint error async/await promise callback function
I am getting an error on eslint expecting ( and not a { here.
loginStateChanged: async (params) => {                                      
                                     ^ Expected '(' and instead saw '{'.

I can't seem to figure out what is going on with the error here.  When I run the grunt build it says this and when looking at the file and code it is listed in, I am not seeing the issue.  The function is a call back and I know that you have to handle the promised return, as specified in this post
Why am I getting an ESLint error for async function with Promise return?
Here is the function:
loginStateChanged: async (params) => {
    UiApi.Logger.debug('ProductHooks', 'onLoginStateChanged', params);
    if (params.state !== 'WORKING') return;
    await CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables();
}

However, I cannot get the syntax down.
Thank you!
I tried updating settings.json to
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {       
        "source.fixAll": "explicit"
    },
    "jshint.optoins": {
    "esversion": 6
    },
    "eslint.validate": ["javascript"] 
}

and I have updated my eslint file here
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        commonjs: true,
        es6: true   
    },
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:requirejs/recommended'],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: 'module'
    },
    globals: {
        _: 'readonly',
        $: 'readonly',
        jQuery: 'readonly'
    },
    rules: {
        'max-len': ['warn', { code: 260 }],
        'function-paren-newline': ['warn', 'never'],
        quotes: ['warn', 'single'],
        'comma-dangle': ['warn', 'never'],
        'no-unused-vars': 'warn'
    },
    plugins: ['requirejs'],
        ignorePatterns: ['GruntFile.js', 'src/libconfig.js', '.data', 'dist', 'libs', 'out', 'tmp']
    };


What is the full eslint error? How up to date is your eslint?

20 |                 loginStateChanged: async (params) => {
^ Expected '(' and instead saw '{'.
that is the full eslint error and the eslint is as specified in package.json as
dependencies: {
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.25.1",
"eslint-plugin-requirejs": "^4.0.1",
...},
devDependencies: {
"eslint": "^7.26.0",
....}

You're at least 2 major eslint versions behind. The error somewhat suggest to me that this could be the issue, but can't be certain. Consider starting with getting things up to date.

Is that the full code? This does indeed look like a syntax error. Or is it part of a class definition or object literal?

"esversion": 6 doesn't have async functions, but eslint should probably ignore jshint.optoins.

loginStateChanged: async (params) => { Expected '(' and instead saw '{'.
CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables(); Expected ')' to match '{' from line 20 and instead saw 'CommonFunctions'.
CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables(); Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables(); Expected '}' to match '{' from line 16 and instead saw 'refreshCallVariables'.
CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables(); Bad invocation on '('
CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables(); Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.

@Bergi here is the full code
applicationApi.subscribe({
            sessionInitialized: () => {},

             loginStateChanged: async (params) => {
                UiApi.Logger.debug('ProductHooks', 'onLoginStateChanged', params);
                if (params.state !== 'WORKING') {return}
                await CommonFunctions.refreshCallVariables();
            }
        });

